# Parse Error in PHP Code (unexpected T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

I am trying to run the following code:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT s.* FROM Table1 s WHERE id=" . $row[1] . ";"
        $mysqli->query($query);
        $query = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE id=" . $row[1] . ";"
        $mysqli->query($query);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

But it's returning:

```
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Anyone know what it could be?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE ...

Comment: you forgot a ; in the line just before.

Comment: HTML/CSS reputation. He's learning PHP I guess.
@Satch3000 You need to learn how to concatenate variables in PHP because this isn't good.
$var = "some string whatever".$avariable."; (semi colon ends the line and isn't part of the query itself)

Comment: I knew that btw...just didn't see it. but thanks anyway

Comment: @HugoDozois You saved me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `;` on the end of EVERY line:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT s.* FROM Table1 s WHERE id=" . $row[1] . ";";
                                                                                ^
$query = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE id=" . $row[1] . ";";
                                                       ^
```

Comment: Yeah I see it now. No need to be Rude "Virus721"

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a problem with your query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT s.* FROM Table1 s WHERE id=" . $row[1] . ";"
```

I think it should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT s.* FROM Table1 s WHERE id=" . $row[1];
```

Comment: No. That's not a problem with the query, just a php syntax error. (If you like you can put a ; at end of your PHP MySQL query)

Comment: Ok. Thought that terminating statements with `;` in php is more important than terminating SQL statements with `;` thats all.

Answer (score 1):

He's right, you're missing a semicolon on this line:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT s.* FROM Table1 s WHERE id=" . $row[1] . ";"
```